# what are the differences between import and extends in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am reading 《Flask web development》.
in Example 4-3，

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
```

I'd like to know:
What are the differences between extends and import?(I think they are quite similar in usage.)
In which situation,I will use extends or import?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you `extend` another template the template controls you (the called controls the caller) - only named blocks in the "parent" template will be rendered:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main_content %}
Only shows up if there is a block called main_content
in base.html.
{% endblock main_content%}
```

On the other hand an `import` simply binds the template to a name in your template's scope, and you control when and where to call it (the caller controls the called):

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
Some of your own template code with {{ wtf.calls() }} where it makes sense.
```

Comment: The `wtf` variable name really made me laugh.  Thank you for a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a difference. `{% extends parent.html %}` allows you to render `parent.html` and also override `{% block %}`'s defined in it while `{% import %}` just allows you to access template variables.

So example template is extends `base.html` and imports variables from `bootstrap/wtf.html`. Think about it like python's class inheritance and import statement.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, included templates are passed the current context and imported templates are not. 
>   [Jinja documentation](http://By%20default,%20included%20templates%20are%20passed%20the%20current%20context%20and%20imported%20templates%20are%20not.)

By default will the included templates not be cached while the imported will.

The reason for this is that imports often are used as a module that holds macros.

The best practice will be to use import on templates that contain macro's while include is best to use when you just wan't some markup template.